# MYSQL joins not working as expected

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am trying to create a join statement to solve my problem but cannot get my head around it.

I am a new to join statements so please bear with me if my sql statement is nonsense.

I have two tables, one is a table of questions where users have asked questions about items for sale.

Second is a table of items that the user has asked a question about.

Table one called `questions` consists of `question_ref, questioner_user_ref, item_ref, seller_ref, question_text, timestamp`

```
questions
===========
+--------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
| question_ref |questioner_user_ref |item_ref |seller_ref |question_text |timestamp |
+--------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

Table two called `my_item_comments` consists of `questioner_ref, item_ref, last_question_ref`

```
my_item_comments
===========
+---------------+---------+------------------+
|questioner_ref |item_ref |last_question_ref |
+---------------+---------+------------------+
```

I have set up table two to keep track of items that the user has asked questions about so they can be informed when someone else asks the seller a question or the seller answers.

So I want to create a recordset of questions that 
a). Someone has answered a question about an item the user is selling 
b). A seller has replied to a question the user asked,
c). A third user has asked a question about an item that the user has also asked a question about.

A bit like facebook's commenting system, where you are informed about comments people have made on statuses that you have commented on.

So my current sql statement is as follows

```
$user_ref= current logged in user


  $sql=mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM questions
    LEFT JOIN my_item_comments
    ON questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref
    WHERE questions.questioner_user_ref!='$user_ref'
    AND (questions.seller_ref='$user_ref' OR questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
```

The results don't work and I think its because of the `OR questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref` but for the life of me I cannot work it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it means restructuring my database with more tables or new fields in the tables.

thanks in advance, Barry

Comment: its easy to read with formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM questions
LEFT JOIN my_item_comments ON questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref
WHERE 
   questions.questioner_user_ref != '$user_ref' AND 
   (questions.seller_ref='$user_ref' OR questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

I think you were missing a `)` to enclose the OR clause (in the example above I added it)

Comment: sorry that was a typo, I have the closing ) in my statement, the problem I have is that it returns all questions that are linked to the second table even if the user did not previously comment on the item. My problem is not about the syntax but the structure of the join statement.

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this again ` OR questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref` => this is the joining condition so you should remove the `OR part`

Comment: I did that but it does not return questions the user made that the seller has been replied to

Comment: It's this what you want to find?:  find all questions asked by a user identified by $user_ref (the condition seems to be `questioner_user_ref = '$user_ref'`) and the seller has replied to it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to improve readability for yourself and us so that it is easier to debug and easier for us to help you :-)

```
$q = "
    SELECT * 
      FROM questions
RIGHT JOIN my_item_comments ON questions.item_ref = my_item_comments.item_ref
     WHERE questions.questioner_user_ref != '".$user_ref."'
       AND (    questions.seller_ref = '".$user_ref."' 
            OR  questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref
            )
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC";

$rs = mysql_query($q);
```

And preferably just the query with dummy data

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM questions
RIGHT JOIN my_item_comments ON questions.item_ref = my_item_comments.item_ref
     WHERE questions.questioner_user_ref != 'dummy_ref'
       AND (    questions.seller_ref = 'dummy_ref' 
            OR  questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref
            )
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Try a `right join` for your query. Left join will indeed get all the rows.

Comment: thanks Richard, but its not the syntax I am having problems with, its the actual statement, it is not giving me the results I require

Comment: I have tried `right join`, `left join`, `inner join`, but it still returns the same thing, the strange thing is that when I run a `mysql_fetch_array` `while` loop, the `questioner_seller_ref` is always the same even when there are other `questoner_user_ref` in the table. This is why I am questioning the sql statement

Comment: OK so I have changed the statement to `$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions LEFT JOIN my_item_comments ON questions.item_ref=my_item_comments.item_ref WHERE questions.questioner_user_ref!='$user_ref' OR questions.lister_ref='$user_ref' ORDER BY timestamp DESC");` and when I check the results it is come back with the correct results...nearly!!

Comment: I have entered dummy data into the tables where I have asked two questions and then the other user has replied to those two questions and has asked a question about my item. therefore i should return 3 questions. but I am getting 5 questions and when i check the `question_ref` of the questions the statement is returning the list of refs are 1,1,2,2,3.  this is where my knowledge of joins is short. any ideas?

Comment: sorry to make that a bit clearer when I run a `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { echo "question_ref=".$row['question_ref']."<br>"; }` the return is question_ref=52
question_ref=51
question_ref=51
question_ref=50
question_ref=50 when I expected question_ref=50 question_ref=51 question_ref=52, can anyone explain why the join statement is making the loop repeat the `question_ref`

Comment: Right I sorted it out by checking to see if the `question_ref` had been printed before and if so, i ignored it, not sleek but it works, cheers for the input guys